# Measurement invariance: Model fit increases with increasing constraints

Tags: confirmatory-factor, lavaan, invariance, scale-invariance

I have run into the same problem repeatedly, namely that model fit increases with increasing model restraints.

I want to compare measurement invariance on a three-factor model (based on previous CFAs for each sub-sample) consisting of nine items with ordinal scores from 1-4 between two groups (adults[N= 29,000] and adolescents[N = 20,500]). The data set I'm using only contains complete cases. This is the method I followed: [measEq.syntax: Syntax for measurement equivalence](https://rdrr.io/cran/semTools/man/measEq.syntax.html)

Lavaan gives me this warning: "some restricted models fit better than less restricted models; either these models are not nested, or the restricted model failed to reach a global optimum"

I also ran a much simpler test where I treated the item values as numeric. Here, the estimates are as expected, with decreasing model fit for each new constraint. I don’t have a good suggestion for why these “numeric” models work.

Maybe the (ordinal) models are non-nested because the group.equal option is overriding some default in the cfa() function, resulting in more parameters being estimated than in the baseline model - even though the number of constraints then brings the degrees of freedom above the baseline model.

I have tried testing different optimization methods and estimators without any results.

### My specified model

```
    mod.cat <- ' sympt1 =~ item1 + item2 + item3 +
             sympt2 =~ item4 + item5 + item6 + item7
             sympt3 =~ item8 + item9'
```

### CONFIGURAL model: no constraints across groups or repeated measures

```
      syntax.config <- measEq.syntax(configural.model = mod.cat,
                                       data = my_data,
                                       ordered = c("item1", "item2" ...),
                                       parameterization = "theta",
                                       ID.fac = "std.lv", 
                                       ID.cat = "Wu.Estabrook.2016",
                                       group = "group")
     mod.config <- as.character(syntax.config)
     fit.config <- cfa(mod.config, 
                  data = my_data, group = "group",
                  ordered = c("item1", "item2" ...), parameterization = "theta")
```

### THRESHOLD invariance:

```
syntax.thresh <- measEq.syntax(configural.model = mod.cat,
                                           data = my_data,
                                           ordered = c("item1", "item2" ...),
                                           parameterization = "theta",
                                           ID.fac = "std.lv", 
                                           ID.cat = "Wu.Estabrook.2016",
                                           group = "group", 
                                           group.equal = "thresholds")
 
mod.thresh <- as.character(syntax.thresh)
         fit.thresh <- cfa(mod.thresh, 
                   data = my_data, group = "group",
                   ordered = c("item1", "item2" ...), parameterization = "theta")
```

## Reproducible data example

```
set.seed(123) 
responses <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)  # Response categories
n_questions <- 9

#### Response probabilities for children and fathers for each question
prob_children <- c(
  0.735, 0.216, 0.041, 0.009,
  0.735, 0.216, 0.041, 0.009,
  0.735, 0.216, 0.041, 0.009,
  0.735, 0.216, 0.041, 0.009,
  0.735, 0.216, 0.041, 0.009,
  0.735, 0.216, 0.041, 0.009,
  0.735, 0.216, 0.041, 0.009,
  0.735, 0.216, 0.041, 0.009,
  0.735, 0.216, 0.041, 0.009
)

prob_fathers <- c(
  0.9525, 0.0443, 0.0018, 0.0006,
  0.9525, 0.0443, 0.0018, 0.0006,
  0.9525, 0.0443, 0.0018, 0.0006,
  0.9525, 0.0443, 0.0018, 0.0006,
  0.9525, 0.0443, 0.0018, 0.0006,
  0.9525, 0.0443, 0.0018, 0.0006,
  0.9525, 0.0443, 0.0018, 0.0006,
  0.9525, 0.0443, 0.0018, 0.0006,
  0.9525, 0.0443, 0.0018, 0.0006
)

##### Random responses for children and fathers for each question
n_children <- 20500
n_fathers <- 29000

children_data <- lapply(1:n_questions, function(q) {
  sample(responses, n_children, replace = TRUE, prob = prob_children[(q - 1) * 4 + 1:4])
})

fathers_data <- lapply(1:n_questions, function(q) {
  sample(responses, n_fathers, replace = TRUE, prob = prob_fathers[(q - 1) * 4 + 1:4])
})
##### Combining the data into data frames
children_df <- data.frame(Group = rep("Children", n_children), do.call(cbind, children_data))
fathers_df <- data.frame(Group = rep("Fathers", n_fathers), do.call(cbind, fathers_data))

MI_test_data <- rbind(children_df, fathers_df)
```

## Output

### Configural model output

[image: Screenshot of configural/ baseline output]

### Threshold model output

[image: Screenshot of treshold model output]

Comment: Which model outputs are you showing? Can you show the commands you run, followed by the output, to make it clear? (For the models you present, it doesn't appear that "some restricted models fit better than less restricted models".)
Also, it's easier if you don't put in output as images. Format it as code.

Answer (score 2):

> `lavaan gives me this warning: "some restricted models fit better than less restricted models`

That's not what shows in your output.  The threshold-equivalence model has more *df* and the chi-squared statistic is higher, relative to the configural model.  If you compared those 2 models with `lavTestLRT()` or `anova()`, I see no reason why that warning would appear.  If you can post a single, simple, reproducible R script + data demonstrating that this happens, it would make it possible to track down a bug.